# Installing a VM using VBoxManage commands fails with NS_ERROR_FAILURE

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, gui, headless

I'm trying to set-up a `VirtualBox VM`, so that at the end of the process, an installation of Linux will start from the virtual DVD.
 Alas, at the end of the set-up process I get an `NS_ERROR_FAILURE` error:

```
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage createvm --name openstack101 --ostype Ubuntu_64 --register
Virtual machine 'openstack101' is created and registered.
UUID: 2a0fee1a-98c0-4f7d-9344-90eefcf75f05
Settings file: '/home/openstack/VirtualBox VMs/openstack101/openstack101.vbox'
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage modifyvm openstack101 --memory 2048 --nic1 nat --nic2 hostonly --hostonlyadapter2 vboxnet0 --nic3 hostonly --hostonlyadapter3 vboxnet1
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage modifyvm openstack101 --nic1 nat --natpf2 ssh,tcp,,4400,,22
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage createhd --filename openstack101.vdi --size 204800
%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Disk image created. UUID: 37e1ed19-8a3a-45b9-b0a3-a8af101ea165
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage storagectl openstack101 --name "SATA Controller" --add sata --controller IntelAHCI --hostiocache on --bootable on
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage storagectl openstack101 --name "IDE Controller" --add ide --controller PIIX4 --hostiocache on --bootable on
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage storageattach openstack101 --storagectl "IDE Controller" --type dvddrive --port 1 --device 0 --medium ~/shared/images/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage modifyvm openstack101 --boot1 dvd
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage modifyvm openstack101 --vrdemulticon on --vrdeport 3390
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage startvm openstack101 --type gui
Waiting for VM "openstack101" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'openstack101' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 0
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component Machine, interface IMachine, callee
openstack@ubuntu:~$
```

Googling for this error message suggests that instead of `VBoxManage startvm openstack101 --type gui,` one should use `VBoxManage startvm openstack101 --type headless.`

When I did that, I did receive:

```
openstack@ubuntu:~$ VBoxManage startvm openstack101 --type headless
Waiting for VM "openstack101" to power on...
VM "openstack101" has been successfully started.
```

But do not see any Ubuntu installation starting.

### Can you suggest what should I do differently - to succeed in installing a VM using VBoxManage commands?

Answer (score 2):

You have your VM been up and running, but you need a viewer to "see" it.  Here is the command to bring up a viewer,

```
rdesktop -a 16 -N [host server ip]:3390
```

Alternatively, power on your VM with the following command, and you will find the port number which VRDE server will be listening

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm openstack101
```

Then, run rdesktop command above with the proper port number (3390 or others)

See [VirtualBox User Manual, Chapter 7: Remote virtual machines](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html).

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem. I was resolved with same version the VBox and guest additions. If not  equals uninstall guest additions and install correct versions.